# Как вытащить номер телефона и email из ячейки Excel?

Tags: excel

Мне тут для работы нужно вытащить номер телефона, второй номер телефона (если он есть) и email из вот таких столбцов ниже. Буду очень благодарен, если поможешь:[image: введите сюда описание изображения])

Comment: А что вы уже сделали? невозможно же ПОМОГАТЬ тому, кто сам ничего не делает, верно?

Comment: А зачем делать, если делать не получается?)

Comment: Мне ведь нужна только подсказка, сайт, где глянуть и т.д.

Comment: Увы... При таком бардаке в данных единственная подсказка - искать платную помощь на фриланс-площадках. Простой "кнопки" нет.

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, судя по представленному скриншоту вообще тяжело понять что у вас за данные и в каком виде они представлены.

Во-вторых, одним лишь тегом `excel` никак не определяете саму задачу и конечную цель, а именно в каком виде вы представляете себе конечный результат.

**Однако предположу** из одного лишь скрина, что файл ваш имеет формат `*.csv` и исходя из этого посоветую вам попробовать его открыть правильно, а не бессмысленным забрасыванием его в первый попавшийся редактор.

CSV — по сути текстовый файл, который можно открыть блокнотом и... если это действительно он то вы увидите все данные как построчный читабельный текст **разделённый запятыми (в вашем случае)**. И, если я прав, то вам для начала не помешало бы его открыть как следует в чём вам `LibreOffice` со множеством настроек для этого вида файлов поможет куда больше чем `Excel`. Впрочем может я и ошибаюсь поскольку давно уже Excel не использую.

[image: Пример открытия файла в LO]

Comment: Ответ сам по себе хорош, но в данном случае поможет очень плохо. Если это и csv, то его создатель выбрал очень неудачный разделитель, так как данные внутри колонок разделены тем же самым разделителем.

Comment: @rotabor хотя конечно вы и постарались на славу, но если я прав, то ваши формулы вообще не понадобятся. Достаточно открыть CSV-шку правильно и будет у него таблица похлеще вашего результата.  Не исключено, что даже что пробелы вернуться в строй.

Comment: Точно, будет похлеще: строки с различным количеством полей - вы на данные-то посмотрите. И потом придётся писать какие-то формулы или макрос на VBA, чтобы искать "концы".

Comment: Его данные я внимательно посмотрел ещё до того как начать писать ответ. И, могу повториться, если я прав, то в случае CSV и везении откроется лучше и могут вернуться пробелы. А у вас?.)

Comment: То есть вы думаете, что в CSV пробелы были, но если его открыли просто как текстовый файл, то они куда-то исчезли?

Comment: И каков будет результат рабора строк "450078гУфа,а/я486,79272363032,3472663032,arbitr_ufa@bk.ru" и "адрес:450052,РеспубликаБашкортостан,г.Уфа,ОПС№52,а/я41,89876030458,baytimirovaartlex@list.ru"?

Comment: Почти уверен в этом. Посмотрите внимательно на скриншот импорта, который я притащил. Пробелы тоже бывают разделителем. Которые мог захавать Ыксель. Одно время часто сталкиваться с разной кривизны CSV. Недавно кстати тоже (10 лет спустя.) но там помимо относительно малой кривизны и файлы по 400 мегов, которые приходится парсить.   Увы, но не видя сырых данных мы можем только догадываться что там у него.

Comment: Так куда и как исчезли пробелы, если файл открыли просто как текст безо всякого разбора?

Comment: Нас тут перду-перждалка гонит в чат, а мне лень вдаваться в дебаты. Буду краток — он открыл файл, а не импортировал. Результат может быть каким угодно даже в зависимости от версии Экселя.)

Comment: Не бывает такого. Если файл открыть просто как текстовый, его содержимое не меняется, строки разбивабтся по строкам Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Разбор csv вам, конечно, поможет, но потом всё равно нужно будет обрабатывать результат.

Я предлагаю вариант с разбором данных, но получше.

Исходя из формата данных, следующие формулы могут сильно облегчить вам задачу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
[B2]=LET(a;TEXTSPLIT(A2;",");b;COLUMNS(a);CHOOSECOLS(a;b;b-1;b-2))
[E2]=LET(a;TEXTSPLIT(B2;":");CHOOSECOLS(a;COLUMNS(a)))
[F2]=LET(a;IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(C2);0);IF(a>0;a;""))
[G2]=LET(a;IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(D2);0);IF(a>0;a;""))
```

B2, E2, F2 и G2 нужно размножить вниз.

Итак, вы получите адрес электронной почты в E и номера телефонов в F и G.

Потом нужно сделать обзор полученного результата и, при необходимости, исправить что-то вручную. На картинке мы видим плохие значения в E4 и E5. Нужно отредактировать исходные данные: в A4 добавить запятые вокруг номера телефона, в A5 - удалить текст "эл.почта" или поставить после него двоеточие.